# How do I fill order id when creating orders and orderitems table with 1 form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How do I fill order id when creating orders and orderitems table with 1 form ?

I make order management system by laravel.

When user submit form of order it will create orders and orderitems table where orderitems table has 1 column named `order_id`. I do not understand how I fill `order_id` in `orderitems` table.

This is my OrderController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
    ]);

    $orderitem = Orderitem::create([
        'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
        'product_id' => $request->input('product_id'),
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
    ]);

    $orderitem = Orderitem::create([
        'order_id' => $order->id,
        'product_id' => $request->input('product_id'),
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a relationships in both model. In the `Order` model create a `hasMany` relation:

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Then in `OrderItem` model create a reverse relation:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

Then finally in the controller

```
$order = Order::create([
    'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
]);

$orderItems = $order->orderItems()->create([
    'product_id' => $request->input('product_id'),
    'quantity' => $request->input('quantity')
]);
```